# in Map/Reduce , could only reduce be restarted?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Is it possible to restart only reduce job in map/reduce job? my guess is 'No' but just want to see if someone has other thoughts about it.

Comment: if only reduce task is failing, and map tasks take long time to complete

Comment: If the reduce task is failing then the Hadoop framework will restart the reduce task. And if the map task is taking too much of time, then the size of the InputSplit can be decreased, more resources can be allocated to the task - there are couple of ways to mitigate the long running tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce is not a "Job" it is a task inside your job.
A job consists of n map tasks and m reduce tasks.

Each task can be restarted.

Comment: I apologize for calling reduce a job, how can I restrat a reduce task?

Comment: You can't. It is restarted by the scheduler after a failure occured.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you need to set up the corresponded mapper to run the reducer. But you can run only with the mapper side, in that case the reducer number would be 0.